# Send Email to Admin After Customer Registration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, email, notification

Trying to follow thuis tutorial:
https://magecomp.com/blog/send-email-to-admin-after-customer-registration-magento-2/

What i have done:

1. \app\code\Namespace\Modulename\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"> 
<module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="0.0.1">
</module> </config>
```

2. \app\code\Namespace\Modulename\registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Namespace_Modulename',
__DIR__
);
```

3. \app\code\Namespace\Modulename\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="customer_register_success">
            <observer name="sendmail_toadmin" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\SendMailToAdmin"/>
        </event>
    </config>
```

4. \app\code\Namespace\Modulename\Observer\SendMailToAdmin.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Namespace_Modulename\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class SendMailToAdmin implements ObserverInterface
    {

        const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'trans_email/ident_general/email';
        protected $_transportBuilder;
        protected $inlineTranslation;
        protected $scopeConfig;
        protected $storeManager;
        protected $_escaper;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
            \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
        ) {
            $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
            $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {


            $customer = $observer->getData('customer');

            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            try 
            {
                $error = false;

                $sender = [
                    'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getFirstName()),
                    'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getEmail()),
                ];
                $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                $postObject->setData($sender);
                $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
                $transport = 
                    $this->_transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('13') // Send the ID of Email template which is created in Admin panel
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // using frontend area to get the template file
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                    ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage(); ;
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();


            } 
            catch (\Exception $e) 
            {
                \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($e->getMessage());
            }

        }

    }
```

Error in browser:

Fatal error: Cannot declare class Namespace_Modulename\Observer\SendMailToAdmin, because the name is already in use in /home/qg2ylpmw/public_html/app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Observer/SendMailToAdmin.php on line 7

What's wrong?? What i need to do to get to work?

Magento ver. 2.2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this **namespace Namespace_Modulename\Observer;** to

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;
```

[Update]

> Do you use module name as **Namespace_Modulename**?

If your answer is yes, then rename it to something that is not **Namespace**. Ex. **AnaMagento_Modulename**. Now replace **Namespace** to **AnaMagento**.

**[Update]**

> app\code\AnaMagento\Modulename\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AnaMagento_Modulename" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app\code\AnaMagento\Modulename\registration.php

```
<?PHP 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'AnaMagento_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app\code\AnaMagento\Modulename\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="sendmail_toadmin" instance="AnaMagento\Modulename\Observer\SendMailToAdmin"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> app\code\AnaMagento\Modulename\Observer\SendMailToAdmin.php

```
<?php

namespace AnaMagento\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SendMailToAdmin implements ObserverInterface
{

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'trans_email/ident_general/email';
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $_escaper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
    ) {
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {


        $customer = $observer->getData('customer');

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try
        {
            $error = false;

            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getFirstName()),
                'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getEmail()),
            ];
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($sender);
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport =
                $this->_transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('13') // Send the ID of Email template which is created in Admin panel
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // using frontend area to get the template file
                            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                    ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage(); ;
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();


        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Now the error is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Namespace' (T_NAMESPACE), expecting '{' in /home/qg2ylpmw/public_html/app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Observer/SendMailToAdmin.php on line 3

Comment: Change module name, check updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry, it shows again the same error =(

Fatal error: Cannot declare class AnaMagento_Modulename\Observer\SendMailToAdmin, because the name is already in use in /home/qg2ylpmw/public_html/app/code/AnaMagento/Modulename/Observer/SendMailToAdmin.php on line 7

Comment: i need to change SendMailToAdmin.php, right? and the same for the other files... because that's what i did...

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so so so so so SOOO much :)

Comment: great, accept this answer that will help other.